# You have no keys in this region yet

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I set up a Luis App in the Azure Portal with Location Australia South East.
I can see the Keys in the Azure Portal.
However when I try to publish the Lewis App, when I click Add Key for Australia Regions  there is a message "You have no keys in this region yet."
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** Any new LUIS endpoint keys created in Azure portal do not appear on the publish page. You need to explicitly add the endpoint keys to publish page.

**Reason for not showing:**

If you created app in [www.luis.ai](http://www.luis.ai) the region will be selected as West US.

[image: Resource1]

Since, I have created LUIS app in [www.luis.ai](http://www.luis.ai) by default in West US, the keys in other regions shows as "You have no keys in this region yet".

[image: Resource2]

If I go to Resource and Keys in Australia Regions it will shows as “You have no keys in this region” because the LUIS app was created on  https://www.luis.ai can be published to all endpoints except the in European i.e, West US.

If LUIS apps created on [au.luis.ai](http://au.luis.ai) can be published to all endpoints except the Australian regions.

[image: Resource3]

If you have created LUSI app in the Azure Portal, you can Manage your LUIS endpoints keys by clicking the Add Key button to open the Assign a key to your app dialog.

[image: Resource3-add]

Successfully added the key to LUIS App in Australia region.

[image: Add-key]

If you want to use a key other than the free Starter_Key shown, click the Add Key button. This action opens a dialog that allows you to select an existing endpoint key to assign to the app. For more information on how to create and add endpoint keys to your LUIS app, see [Manage your keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-manage-keys).

For more details, refer “[Publishing to Australia](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-regions#publishing-to-australia)”.